# proper way of implementing CompareTo method

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

I'm trying to understand proper implementation and usage of CompareTo method.

Let's say that I have Book object and somewhere in code I want to compare newly created book object with one from the database.

```
Book newBook = new Book();
Book dbBook = repository.GetBook(1);
```

so basically I'm trying to compare two objects with multiple parametars

- Title
- Edition
- Language

roughly I have following bellow, so how would you implement this method having those 3 requirements?

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Book)
    {
      Book b = (book)obj;
      var b = Name.ToUpper().CompareTo(b.Name.ToUpper());
    }
    else
    { throw new Exception("Not a book instance"); }

}
```

Comment: `CompareTo` is meant to provide an ordering for objects of the type, which means book A might be "smaller" than book B. How do you define "smaller" for books?

Comment: @Jon, it doesn't mean "smaller", it means "comes before when ordered". So OP is saying that, in order to sort books, one must first sort on title, then on edition, and finally on language.

Comment: @RoyDictus: That's exactly what "smaller" in quotes means; the term is used in the generalized sense, which is [pretty common practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx). Also, IMO the question does not explicitly specify the ordering relationship you describe so instead of assuming I asked.

Comment: Seems likely that you'd want to compare {by title, by edition, by language} in that order, which is the order in which the OP listed the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's better to use generics, to to define your Book class as:

```
public class Book : IComparable<Book>
```

and then to implement the `CompareTo` method:

```
public int CompareTo(Book book)
{
    int result = Title.CompareTo(book.Title);
    if (result == 0)
    {
       result = Edition.CompareTo(book.Edition);
       if (result == 0)
       {
            result = Language.CompareTo(book.Language);
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This of course assumes that the properties `Title`, `Edition` and `Language` are of types that implement `IComparable` (such as `string`).

Comment: OP seems to want to ignore case (note his use of `ToUpper()`) so perhaps the comparisons would better be: `int result = string.Compare(this.Title, book.Title, ignoreCase:true);`